# How to burn an audio CD in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cd-burning

I used to use the built in Windows Media Player to burn audio CDs under Win 8. Now that it has been removed in Windows 10 is there a built in option to do this?

If there is not what would you recommend as an alternative. iTunes is the obvious one that springs to mind but I don't find it very user friendly for something like this.

Comment: Wouldn't a program like CDBurnerXP be easier? I can be portable and will probably be supported for a long time.

Comment: Have you tried the Music App? Or have you looked in the Windows Store to see if there is an App available to do what you want?

Comment: @sigalor CDBurnerXP does look easy. I've downloaded it and will give it a try later. Thanks

Comment: @CharlieRB I was hoping for a built in method first. I am aware that the new Microsoft Groove app does not do this. Also I imagine that a store app is much less likely to support this than a desktop app.

Comment: You may want to update your question to include those details. When I burned a CD, I did it directly from Windows Explorer. It gives the option to make an audio or data CD when you select burn. Have you tried that?

Comment: @CharlieRB I did include in the question that I was after a builtin method. In windows explorer it does give the option to burn like a usb drive or to be able to use in a cd/dvd player. I could be wrong but I think the cd/dvd player option burns files like mp3s as they are (which some cd players can handle), it does not burn as a standard music cd.

Comment: I meant to add the details about what you had tried with Groove. As far as the choice in Windows Explorer, the data option copies as MP3 while the audio option converts to be played like a standard audio CD. I have used it. Give it a try to see if it meets your "built in" criteria.

Comment: @CharlieRB I tried the explorer options and can confirm it burns it as mp3 files. See http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows7/burn-a-cd-or-dvd-in-windows-explorer there are 2 formats explorer burns in - live file system format and mastered format.

Answer (score 11):

I found a solution for you. Actually, you may still have the built-in Windows Media Player, but it's hidden, because you have the new metro apps.

```
    Here's how:
```

1.Go to C:/Program Files

2.Search for the folder *Windows Media Player*

If there isn't a folder with that name, search in *Program Files (x86)*, in case you have Windows 10 64-Bit edition.

If you don't find it anywhere,it may not be included with your copy of Windows (i have Windows 10 Pro).

To check if you have the Media Features, right-click on the start button and select **Control Panel** . Then, go to:

*Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off* (on the left side)

Scroll down until you see a folder named *Media Features*. Go to it and you should see a folder named *Windows Media Player*. Check the box to install it.
[image]

If you installed Windows Media Player, go to it and double click *wmplayer.exe*

[image]

You may need to set it up before you start. After that, you can enjoy creating audio CDs

Comment: I also have Win10 Pro however I did a fresh install rather than upgraded from Win8 so I'm guessing that's why I don't have it. Nice find tho.

Comment: Actually the exact version I have is 'Windows Pro N' which according to http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-8/upgrade-to-n doesn't ship with media player even in Win 8. My prev Win8 version was enterprise.

Comment: That's the reason you don't have Windows Media Player installed.You need to install it or any other 3rd party app like iTunes to burn CDs

Comment: You can get Windows Media Player on 'K' and 'N' editions of Windows by installing the Media Feature Pack: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30685

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score -1):

It's in the start menu under all apps scroll all the way down to windows accessories and Windows Media player is there

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.  Especially on older questions or on question which already have detailed answers, both of which are true here